# Java embedded with html

Tags: java, jquery, html

Is it possible to embed html with java

test.html

```
   <input id="buttonId" type="button" class="button-click"
    value="" onClick="checkSucess(2)" onload="counts(count)">
```

test.js

```
 checkSucess = function(firstVal) {

    // Jquery Ajax with url,params and response
      doPost('test.java',
        'first=' + firstVal,
       function(response) {

       });
```

test.java

```
Here get the 'first' value from ajax request, and further processing.
```

Comment: Huh? What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @BrianRoach : I want to know whether pure html code be used with Java, not applet/Swing etc.

Comment: Java has a string type, right? Then the answer is "yes". But that's not a meaningful answer, because you haven't asked a meaningful question, really. *What are you trying to do?*

Comment: @all: I am basically a PHP developer, doing my first assign in java. So I go in control flow from Html to javascript then to java

Comment: @Jusnit - Again, not sure what you mean by "pure html code" here. You seem to be wanting to do an AJAX request to something written in Java. You would need to write a Java servlet to handle that (running in a container such as Tomcat).

Comment: As an aside, the handler name is "onclick" not "onClick"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're looking for **JavaServer Pages *(.jsp)***, a starting point for implementing server-side logic using Java. (You can GET/POST to a *jsp*.)

**Reference**

- [JSP + Ajax Example](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples)
- [JavaServer Pages Technology](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html)
- [JSP Tutorial](http://www.jsptut.com/Sessions.jsp)

Answer (score 2):

Well, Java on the server side doesn't work quite like PHP. i.e. you can't simply drop your java files in your htdocs directory and trigger it by filename directly. Firstly you'll need an app server like tomcat or jetty (instead of just a webserver like apache httpd). Secondly, you'll need to create a Servlet (simplest case) and write your java code there and trigger it using the server request url. Google "servlets" and you should be able to pick it from there..

Answer (score 0):

Applets are Java, and the only (usual) way for Java in the browser.

You can communicate with Applets from Javascript/JQuery code. Applets have ending .class (.java is source code, you can't communicate with it).

In the case you want to communicate with serverside Java, you need servlets there. Then send requests to the url of the servlets.

Comment: Of course there are other ways to run Java on the client side, but applets will let you embed Java in a web page.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do like that, you have to use AJAX request to interact with java from your html or javascript. For that you have to use servlet and pass the servlet URL to doPost function.

```
doPost('url to servlet',
        'first=' + firstVal,
       function(response) {

       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is your first java project, you should do some reading to come up to speed with java.  Here are some good tutorials:

[Core Servlets, Intermediate Servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/csajsp2.html)

[Apache Tomcat 6](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/) - Apache is a nice tool for learning servlets; it is easy to install and run.

[Core Servlets; Advanced Servlets](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/msajsp.html) - This may be more than you need.

Answer (score 0):

**No.** Besides using Java Applets - which are actually just plugins - there is no way to embed Java into HTML.

That being said, It is possible to ***generate*** HTML using Java Server Pages.

It is also possible to use an HTML page in conjunction with JavaScript to interact with Java via subsequent HTTP Requests made using AJAX. These requests are initiated on the client browser, and received and fulfilled by a server capable of executing Java Server Pages (JPS).

Example:

1. An HTML page is loadad with some JavaScript that requests some url upon completion of DOM loading.
2. The request is received by some server which then responds to the request.
3. The client browser receives the response and provides it to JavaScript to be dealt with.
4. JavaScript reads the response, and uses it in some way (like "refreshing" some information on the page).